# In C, what is a safer function to use than strtrns?

Tags: c, security, code-analysis

strtrns has the following descriptions: [desc-1](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/3gen/strtrns/),   [desc-2](https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/coding/855-BSI.html)

> The  strtrns() function transforms  string and copies it into 
>   result.
>          Any character  that appears in  old is replaced with the  character  in
>          the same position in  new. The  new result is returned.   .........
>
> This function is a security risk because it is possible to overflow
>   the newString buffer. If the currentString buffer is larger than the
>   newString buffer, then an overflow will occur.

And this is its prototype( or "signature"? ":

```
char * strtrns(const char *string, const char *old, const char *new, char *result);
```

I've been googling to no avail. I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic, but why doesn't your description match the signature (oldsegment/newsegment/newString/currentString don't match anything)

Comment: You can't be too pedantic! I gotta learn this well! Thank You,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can write your own safe one pretty quickly.

It won't be a direct replacement, as the signature is slightly different, and it will allocate memory that the caller must free, but it can serve mostly the same job.

*(I'm also changing the parameter name `new`, which is a reserved word in C++, and the parameter `string` which is a very common type in C++.
  These changes makes the function compatible with C++ code as well)*

```
char* alloc_strtrns(const char *srcstr, const char *oldtxt, const char *newtxt)
{
    if (strlen(oldtxt) != strlen(newtxt))
    {
        return NULL;    /* Old and New lengths MUST match */
    }

    char* result = strdup(srcstr);    /* TODO: check for NULL */
    /* Caller is responsible for freeing! */

    return strtrns(srcstr, oldtxt, newtxt, result);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the result string of strtrns can be a different length than the input?  According to the man page, it simply is a direct character-by-character replacement, which means the result would be the exact same length as the original string.  Also, the first call in here to strtrns might crash since the new string is zero length.  The one implementation of strtrns I looked at assumed that the new and old buffers were the same length.  One other potential issue is that this can't be a direct replacement since the caller must free the result in this version.

Comment: @MarkWilkins:  Interesting, I did find conflicting documentation of strtrns, some saying it does a 1-to-1 character replacement, and some saying it does a string-based "search-and-replace".   I guess I can't be sure what implementation OP Adel has.

Comment: @abelenky:  The link to a man page in the OP seems to indicate the former (1-to-1 replacement).

Comment: What the OP cites as "desc-2" appears to be flat-out wrong when it says "The strtrns function will take the currentString and replace every instance of oldsegment with newsegment."   All other documentation says it will do a 1-for-1 character replacement.  I'm editing out my code, meant to fix a problem that doesn't really exist.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, as the memory allocation is a quite large side-effect. I'm all for writing your own function, but I'd recommend adding a limit parameter instead.

Comment: @Tobias:  In working with the original strtrns, you pretty much need to allocate your own memory (unless referring to stack-space, or pre-allocated memory).  I don't see that it matters so much if the caller or the callee makes the allocation.  Either way, it must (generally) be made.

Comment: Of course you have to allocate memory, I'm just saying the memory shouldn't be allocated within the function as it's hidden :)
The reason I'm suggesting a limit parameter is that I don't like null arguments, which would be necessary in order to for example calculate the required buffer size in a first call in order to allocate it and then call the function with that buffer as an argument. And the reason I don't like null arguments is that you get a function that does two completely different things depending on the abstract concept of null, passed as an argument...

Answer (score 2):

The claim that this function is unsafe is nonsense. In C, whenever you have an interface that takes a pointer to a buffer and fills it with some amount of data, you must have a contract between the caller and callee regarding the buffer size. For some functions where the caller cannot know in advance how much data the callee will write, the most logical interface design (contract) is to have the caller pass the buffer size to the callee and have the callee return an error or truncate the data if the buffer is too small. But for functions like `strcpy` or in your case `strtrns` where the number of output bytes is a trivial function (like the identity function) of the number of input bytes, it makes perfectly good sense for the contract to simply be that the output buffer provided by the caller must be at least as large as the input buffer.

Anyone who is not comfortable with strict adherence to interface contracts should not be writing C. There is really no way around this; adding complex bounds-checking interfaces certainly does not solve the problem but just shifts around the nature of the contracts you have to follow.

By the way, `strtrns` is not a standard function anyway so if you'd prefer a different contract anyway you might be better off writing your own similar function. This would increase portability too.

Comment: R.. - thanks for this - it's what people seem to forget about C - you're given enough rope to hang yourself (or not) as you see fit (and are capable) - There is no such thing as 'entry level' C

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have any options in C. You simply have to ensure that the destination buffer is large enough.

Comment: Uhhh....  No options?  How hard would it be, in C, to rewrite this little function?  Personally, I've had times when I had to write snprintf(), so I think it can be done.

Comment: Of course it can be rewritten, but I interpreted the question as the OP wanted to know of alternative functions.

Comment: You've got to be careful on SO, not to open the door to C bashing.  As you can see, I've been here a while, so I have moved on from careful to paranoid.  :)